# Impossible to change window title with GWT once reverse proxy is set

Tags: apache, tomcat, gwt

I am currently developping a GWT application for my institute (source code : https://github.com/eufarn7sp/asmm-eufar-java). For testing purpose, I installed Tomcat 8 on my own server (amateur stuff, hosting already an apache php server to serve a php forum to me and my friends, nothing critical), and deployed my app on it. It is available following this link : http://176.31.165.18:8080/asmm-eufar/

As I wanted to remove the ip address and port number in the URL (reverse proxy), I activated mod_proxy for apache, following a tutorial. Here is the link: http://www.orion-universe.eu/asmm-eufar/. 99% of the application is ok and work as it should. BUT it seems that my app can't modify the title in the browser tab. It should display "ASMM Creator" and be updated once the user modify the form. I used the usual command to set the window title :

```
Window.setTitle("blablabla");
```

As I am not an expert in server administration, I can't see what I am doing wrong here. Here is the code I used in the conf file of apache :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerName orion-universe.eu

     ProxyRequests On
     ProxyPass /asmm-eufar http://localhost:8080/asmm-eufar
     ProxyPassReverse /asmm-eufar http://localhost:8080/asmm-eufar

     <Location "/asmm-eufar">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't control how the title is set or changed.

Instead, something other than your proxy is happening - your `orion-universe.eu` server isn't actually proxying the call, but is instead showing an HTML page which is only an `<iframe>`... which then points at the original page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>www.orion-universe.eu</title>
  </head>
  <frameset>
    <frame src="http://176.31.165.18/asmm-eufar/" name="redir">
    <noframes>
      <p>Original location:
        <a href="http://176.31.165.18/asmm-eufar/">http://176.31.165.18/asmm-eufar/</a>
      </p>
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

This then loads `http://176.31.165.18/asmm-eufar/` in an the frame, so it cannot control the *outer* page's title (which is why loading both http://176.31.165.18/asmm-eufar/ and http://www.orion-universe.eu/asmm-eufar/ have different initial titles too).

Your proxy-pass *looks* right, but something else is causing this - find out where that html file with the iframe is, and see what might be causing your server to serve it instead.

---

In re-reading the proxypass, one thing jumps out at me: you are redirecting to localhost:8080, but your server isnt running there:

```
 ProxyPass /asmm-eufar http://localhost:8080/asmm-eufar
```

Don't you mean for that to say something like

```
 ProxyPass /asmm-eufar http://176.31.165.18:8080/asmm-eufar
```

Same for the second line. This does seem to assume that you have two different servers, and one is a proxy for the other, but still doesn't clarify why the iframe is shown, unless that is what localhost:8080 is serving?

Comment: You are right, using the ip adress gave what I am waiting for : the tab title is working as it should. From my side, I had also the feeling a webpage embedding in another webpage. My lack of knowledge here is surely at fault. How I set the apache server needs a review. I will cancel my modifications and try to understand all their consequences before trying to fix it. Thanks for you help !

Comment: The iframe is what is stopping the title from changing - it is not a proxy, and will cause problems like the title issue. That's all I can say from the GWT side of things, you need to fix the reverse proxy and remove the iframe, possibly by updating your question to _just_ details about the proxy and waiting for more help. I'll add one piece that I see looks wrong, but that's about all I can do, I dont know apache well.

Comment: I modified the ProxyPass parameter to replace localhost by the IP address. The result is the same. As Tomcat and Apache was on the same server, I though localhost would be enough. For now, I will do some test and try to find information, as it seems my conf file is not totally right ("ProxyRequests On" shouldn't be used here according to Apache documentation)

Comment: The key of the problem is that frame ... Once I understand why it appears and how to get rid of it, it should be ok :o) !

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Document.get().setTitle(title);` I'm assuming you're referring to the Document window.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I will try this one once I understand why I have a frame on the webpage.